# Installation failure for Docker on windows 10 enterprise

Tags: docker, windows-10, virtualbox, docker-machine, docker-registry

when I am installing Docker for windows I am facing the below issues. My system OS is windows 10 Enterprise.

```
Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32Error(Int32 errorCode, String str)
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.SetValue(String name, Object value, RegistryValueKind valueKind)
   at CommunityInstaller.AutoStartAction.DoAsync(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<HandleD4WPackageAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<ProcessAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
```

Comment: You need Administrator privileges to install Docker on Windows. Is your user an admin ?

Comment: I have tried installing this using admin, the error is the same .the docker for windows version is 2.3.0.3